# Как запустить сам фреймворк ASP. NET MVC 5 как отдельное приложение и продебажить?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Хотелось бы более-менее нормально изучить MVC 5. Когда смотрю уроки\статьи\чужие программы, то получается что мои знания пополняются конкретными реализациями каких-то вещей. К примеру, "если нужно перед действием выполнить какой-то код, нужно создать фильтр действия и вписать этот в код в специальный метод".

В итоге я что-то умею, но цельной картины нет. Всегда получается зависимость от какого-то "парня, который разобрался и написал об этом". Какой-то крепкой документации по фреймворку нет, чтобы от А до Я было расписано что происходит с того момента, как на серв приходит запрос и до момента, когда серв отправляет ответ обратно браузеру. Это и не удивительно, т.к. поддерживать эту писанину трудно и никому по сути не нужно.

Я взял исходники MVC 5 на гитхабе, некоторые сборки даже компилируются из VS. Но это dll-ки, их очевидно нельзя запускать. Что же делать, чтобы увидеть весь путь запроса?

Comment: Вам пока рано вникать в низкоуровневые дела, но если очень хочется, поизучайте как работает HTTP. Создайте ASP.NET Core Empty проект и попробуйте ответить браузеру HTML страницей, вручную подставив HTTP заголовки. Откройте инструменты разработчика в браузере, вкладку Сеть и посмотрите, что там есть. А потом, шаг за шагом попробуйте преобразовать этот Empty в MVC.

Comment: в программировании одна абстракция строится поверх другой так, чтобы не призодилось вникать в нижнюю часть. Вам достаточн знать то, что написано в документации, так как исхозники завтра перепишут и все ваши знания про то, как оно работает под капотом будут просто не нужны

Comment: @aepot Да как бы и не рано, три с половиной года уже в .net. Причем не дома после смены на складе, а работаю программистом в профильной компании и получаю за это деньги. Иные уже синьорами за такое время становятся (но это не точно) ) Всегда будет рано, если не начать. На всякий случай не буду говорить, на чем я прогал до .net, но там никаких фреймворков не было и даже порой библиотек. Поэтому для меня все еще непривычно писать программу, когда 99% ее работы по сути черный ящик, в которой "здесь подставь и будет норм". Поэтому как раз низкоуровневые дела мне интересны, чем ниже тем лучше даже.

Comment: @Shebbyman хороший подход, я его постоянно использую. Но если встречается что-то незнакомое, я сначала узнаю, зачем оно нужно и как правильно пользоваться, и только потом лезу узнавать, как оно работает на низком уровне.

Comment: @aepot Я не спроста привел пример с фильтрами. Если бы мне не встретилось видео\статья, где про них рассказывается, я бы о них не знал. Я видел код, где люди прокидывали string из методов с текстом ошибки, на всем пути от бизнес-логики до самого действия, вместо того чтобы например выбросить исключение и поймать его в фильтре исключений один раз. Аналогичная ситуация может случиться с любым функционалом. Он есть, а узнаешь о нем или нет - дело случая. Поэтому я и создал вопрос. Хочется иметь шанс самостоятельно попытаться найти что-то интересное.

Comment: узнаешь о нем или нет - дело правильной литературы\курса\чтения документации.

Comment: А это уже все паттерны и навык придет со временем, на лекциях и видосах навык не рождается. А если уметь гуглить, то вообще все выше перечисленное - не проблема.

Comment: Мы конечно мило болтаем, но я честно говоря все-таки ожидаю какой-нибудь помощи с исходным вопросом - как скомпилить и запустить сам фреймворк, а не узнать нужно мне это или нет, рано или не рано. Было б не нужно, не спросил бы. Было бы рано - мне бы это и в голову не пришло. Мб "запустить фреймворк" звучит некорректно, но суть вроде понятна - я хочу поставить точку останова, где-нибудь "внутри" фреймворка, например, в компоненте, который принимает запрос, разбирает его и принимает решение, какой контроллер создать.

Comment: Что вам поможет с пониманием, я описал в самом первом комментарии. Далее, чтобы дебажить фреймворк, вам нужно в настройках отладки студии убрать галочку Just my code и запустить проект. Подтянутся исходники фреймворка и их можно будет пошагово отлаживать.